How do I simplify a likelihood function down further?
Each observation $ l_i $ follows a Binomial distribution:
$$
l_i \sim \text{Binomial}(N, p)
$$
This means that the probability of observing $ l_i $ lizards out of $ N $ on day $ i $ is:
$$
P(l_i \mid N, p) = \binom{N}{l_i} p^{l_i} (1 - p)^{N - l_i}
$$
The likelihood function $L(p)$ is the probability of observing all the data $ l = \{ l_1, l_2, \ldots, l_n \} $ given $ p $:
$$
L(p \mid l, N) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(l_i \mid N, p)
$$
Substitute $P(l_i \mid N, p)$:
$$
L(p \mid l, N) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \binom{N}{l_i} p^{l_i} (1 - p)^{N - l_i}
$$
Simplifying:
$$
L(p \mid l, N) = \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \binom{N}{l_i} \right) p^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i} (1 - p)^{nN - \sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i}
$$
I don't understand the prior step, how is the simplifying step done and where does the $ \Sigma $ come from in the power $p$ and $(1-p)$?

This is just adding exponents: $p^{l_1}p^{l_2}p^{l_3} = p^{l_1+l_2+l_3}$

The formula
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(a_ib_ic_i)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^nb_i\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^nc_i\right)
$$
is used with
$$
a_i=\binom{N}{\ell_{i}},\quad b_i=p^{\ell_i},\quad c_i=(1-p)^{N-\ell_i}.
$$
Then, for the product of the $b_i$, as mentioned by BigBen, the exponent add. For example, $p^{\ell_1}p^{\ell_2}=p^{\ell_1+\ell_2}$, $p^{\ell_1}p^{\ell_2}p^{\ell_3}=p^{\ell_1+\ell_2+\ell_3}$ and so on.
